# $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

It exists a bijection $\psi:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}$.
If on $\{0,1\}$ we put the discrete topology, then are the two spaces above homeomorphic considering the product topology on the first space?

Answer (score 1):

No, because, by Tychonoff's theorem, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is compact.

Comment: My question is due to a discussion about Tyconoff's theorem. Maybe on $\mathbb{R}$ is naturally induced a topology which makes it compact.

Comment: @aleio1 Since you did not state *which* topology you were taking on $\mathbb R$, I assumed that it was the usual one. If it is not, it's up to you to tell us which topology you have in mind.

Comment: I have to think about it. Maybe I had to ask: "Does it exists a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that..". I will try to find it.

Comment: @aleio1 Of course there is! The final topology corresponding to the map $\psi$.